# Testing if a worksheet is undefined VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So at one point I'm testing if the worksheet number being called is greater than the total number of worksheets in a workbook.

```
If SourceWB.Sheets.Count < WorksheetNumber Then
                GoTo ErrorLog
                MsgBox "We're looking for a sheet number higher than the total number of worksheets. For example, we're looking for sheet 3 when there are only 2 sheets in the workbook. Please check your mapping and re-try this workbook."
                Exit Sub
            Else
       'We're good
       End If
```

Ok no problem. My error logging:

```
ErrorLog:


Set ErrorLogSh = wb.Sheets("Error Log")
errorRow = ErrorLogSh.Range("A" & ErrorLogSh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

     ErrorLogSh.Cells(errorRow, 1) = Err.Number
     ErrorLogSh.Cells(errorRow, 2) = Err.Description
     ErrorLogSh.Cells(errorRow, 3) = SourceWB.Name


     ErrorLogSh.Cells(errorRow, 4) = SourceSheet.Name


    Resume Next
```

Issue: When there's no sourcesheet (As defined earlier, we're testing for it), we get a problem. I'm trying to figure out a test for the sourcesheet variable to see if it's blank or not.

Now, the easy, easy solution would be to mimic the same test as earlier. But I got thinking - how could I test if the variable is empty?

Isnull didn't work - it flags it the wrong way. 
A test of = Nothing didn't work - complained that the variable didn't exist

So I'm kind of stuck.

Note: This is a subroutine within a larger macro - could setting the variables to = nothing at the end do the trick?

Comment: Do you mean to test if a sheet exists? If so, you would do that test before If SourceWB.Sheets.Count

Comment: Your `GoTo` logic isn't going to do what you think it's doing - you'll never get to your `MsgBox` or `Exit Sub`. Once you go to `ErrorLog`, your code will continue down the sub until `End Sub`.

Comment: So basically copy and paste the parts of the error log I want instead of the goto portion, and it'll work out.

Comment: Would `SourceSheet.Name = vbNullString` work by any chance?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: No, because if `SourceSheet` is null, you can't access it to see if it has a `Name`.

Comment: @dwirony actually, I'd be expecting "Resume without Error" to be thrown on `Resume Next`. Hard to tell exactly what the OP's problem is when the best you've got is "it doesn't work".

Comment: To test if a variable is Nothing, you have to use `is Nothing`, not `= Nothing`. I frequently make the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for testing is an object = Nothing is `If Object Is Nothing Then`

Also, your ErrorLog needs to account for that too

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WorksheetNumber  As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorLog
    WorksheetNumber = 1
    If SourceWB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "SourceWB is not set"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf SourceWB.Sheets.Count < WorksheetNumber Then
        MsgBox "We're looking for a sheet number higher than the total number of worksheets. For example, we're looking for sheet 3 when there are only 2 sheets in the workbook. Please check your mapping and re-try this workbook."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'We're good
    End If
Exit Sub

ErrorLog:
    Dim errorRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Error Log")
        errorRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Cells(errorRow, 1) = Err.Number
        .Cells(errorRow, 2) = Err.Description
        If SourceWB Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(errorRow, 3) = "Nothing"
        Else
            .Cells(errorRow, 3) = SourceWB.Name
            If SourceSheet Is Nothing Then
                .Cells(errorRow, 4) = "Nothing"
            Else
                .Cells(errorRow, 4) = SourceSheet.Name
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Note that the error log won't be called if `SourceWB` is Nothing or `WorksheetNumber` is > number of Sheets.  If you want to log those errors using the error handler, you need to let the code error, handle it and return

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WorksheetNumber  As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorLog
    WorksheetNumber = 1
    Set SourceSheet = SourceWB.Sheets(WorksheetNumber) '<-- throws an error
    If SourceWB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "SourceWB is not set"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf SourceSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "We're looking for a sheet number higher than the total number of worksheets. For example, we're looking for sheet 3 when there are only 2 sheets in the workbook. Please check your mapping and re-try this workbook."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'We're good
    End If
Exit Sub

ErrorLog:
    Dim errorRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Error Log")
        errorRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Cells(errorRow, 1) = Err.Number
        .Cells(errorRow, 2) = Err.Description
        If SourceWB Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(errorRow, 3) = "Nothing"
        Else
            .Cells(errorRow, 3) = SourceWB.Name
            If SourceSheet Is Nothing Then
                .Cells(errorRow, 4) = "Nothing"
            Else
                .Cells(errorRow, 4) = SourceSheet.Name
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Resume Next
End Sub
```